# Generate digital clock in my form control

Tags: vb.net, clock

This is my first question so please forgive me if there are any mistakes. and also am new to VB.net. Let me come to the point. I wish to show a digital clock which shows the seconds each time without refreshing the page.

Am having a label named `Label1` in which i need to show the time.  I tried it with a loop but shows only a time. how can I make it running when form loads.

My experience with this code is:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 60
    Label1.Text = Now.TimeOfDay.ToString
Next
```

But it shows only once. Am expecting some help to make it running when form loads. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Timer control](http://vb.net-informations.com/gui/timer-vb.htm) for this purpose. the link will guide you to create timer events. Here i suggest some method which create timer dynamically and add events for it through [AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx). consider the following code:

```
    Dim clockTimer As Timer = New Timer 'Creating dynamic timer
    clockTimer.Interval = 1000 'Assign timer interval as 1000ms=1second
    AddHandler clockTimer.Tick, AddressOf clockTick 'add event for the dynamically created controls
    clockTimer.Start()'start the timer
    ' Up to this comes in the form load section
    Public Sub clockTick()' Function which refered by the addhandler
        Label1.Text = Now.TimeOfDay.ToString ' show time in label and are refreshed in each tick(1sec)
    End Sub
```

**Update :** Why your code is not working:

- You are using a `For loop` which iterate the code 60 times but it completes its iteration within a second so you can't able to see the change.
- Instead for this use timer which will execute automatically in the interval specified